# Giving a specific style to DataGrid element (implicitly)

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying implicitly apply a style for DataGrid and TextBlocks.

For TextBlock's ForeGround I need **White** color.

For DataGrid's rows I need **Black** Color.

Beside this I need **White** again for DataGrid's header columns.

[image]

When I globally apply an implicit style for on MainPage by

```
<UserControl>
 <UserControl.Resorces>
    <Style targetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
 </UserControl.Resorces>
</UserControl>
```

Making TextBlock's Foreground White operation is done! But beside this all of elements 
in DataGrid (By default content elements are textblock's I think) turn to White color.

It doesn't look good White on white as you guess :)
So how can I particularly specify DataGrid's elements Foreground to black?

I can do it by using same technic shown below ,but this is an expensive operation for each DataGrid. As a con more I want DataGrid's HeaderColumns white again.This operation make them all black.

Is there an explicit way such as we do in css styles?

Here is what I tried to achieve this goal by Control template. But no chance because of being DataGrid's ContentControl is dynamic.

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style targetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
<DataGrid.Resources>
```

In fact we use Telerik's RadGridView but I give a sdk's DataGrid example to make question more global.

```
<Style TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ControlTemplate1}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate1" TargetType="sdk:DataGrid">
    <Grid/>
</ControlTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
    <Grid/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If it were me I would pull out the full control templates and style them accordingly instead of trying to just do adhoc setter changes to override bits of the original template. In Expression Blend right click, choose "Edit Template -> Edit A Copy" and break out the templates for your rows etc and apply those implicitly with StaticResource instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did it . ControlTemplate1 is DataGrid's template. I applied your advice to Telerik's RadGridView in fact previously.There are dozens of styles you need to set. In fact I solved it after asking this question by using Telerik's GridView parts styling.Anyway you desire an +1 for editing and answering.

Comment: Ya I can tell you from tons of experience, I normally HATE dealing with telerik's control templates. However if you got your answer already be sure and update the thread and mark it answered to help someone in the future :)